# Oriento query builder like clause

Tags: node.js, express, autocomplete, orientdb, oriento

I'm trying to get an autocomplete work with a oriento db interface.

The webserver is nodeJS with express framework and the server code is this:

```
express.get("/piatti", function(req, res) {
    var tipo = req.query.tipo;
    var nome = req.query.nome;

    var filtriRicerca = {};
    var tabella = modules.database.db.select().from('PIATTI');

    if(tipo) {
        filtriRicerca.tipo = tipo;
    }

    if(nome) {
        filtriRicerca.nome = nome;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(filtriRicerca));

    if(Object.keys(filtriRicerca).length) {
        console.log("Aggiunto il filtro");
        tabella = tabella.where(filtriRicerca);
    }

    tabella.all().then(function (piatti) {
        res.json(piatti);
    });
});
```

I cant figure out how to to get the where clause work as 'like filtriRicerca.nome%'.

Thanks in advance, 
Mattia

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Mattia, a possible alternative solution to your problem is to use the Waterline ORM with the [sails-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb) adapter. sails-orientdb uses Oriento so you can access Oriento's methods anytime and you can do `like` queries like this:

```
Model.find({ food: { 'like': '%beans' }})
```

More examples on the [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md#like).